# titleForHeaderInSection in multiple lines (long text)

Tags: ios4, header, grouped-table

I want to display a header title for a grouped table, but it is only displaying in one line. I am not sure if this is possible, but a table cell can be displayed in multiple lines, but I do not know if the header also.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own custom view with as many lines as you like and implement tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: to return the custom view instead of tableView:titleForHeaderInSection.